# How to connect two local networks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, openwrt

I have a my home local network `192.168.1.0/24` (further - LAN), and an OpenWRT router at `192.168.1.1`. And i have homeserver at `192.168.1.5` with multipass (with qemu backend) and virtual machines in `10.57.240.0/24` (further - VM-LAN) network (mpqemubr0 interface).
Also, I have a laptop with the address 192.168.1.137. And I want to have access to the VM-LAN network from the laptop. I added a static route on the OpenWRT router with the settings

```
IP - 10.57.240.0
Netmask - 255.255.255.0
Gateway - 192.168.1.5
```

When I ping 10.57.240.47 from my laptop I get an error

```
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
```

ipv4_forward at 192.168.1.5 is enabled.

homeserver info:

```
h3xcode@h3x-homeserver:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:17:9b:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 42394sec preferred_lft 42394sec
    inet6 fdaa:c0de:c0de::5/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdaa:c0de:c0de:0:6e3b:e5ff:fe17:9b70/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6e3b:e5ff:fe17:9b70/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: mpqemubr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d9:01:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.57.240.1/24 brd 10.57.240.255 scope global mpqemubr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed9:122/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
h3xcode@h3x-homeserver:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.5 metric 100 
10.7.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.1 
10.57.240.0/24 dev mpqemubr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.57.240.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 100 
192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

```
h3xcode@h3x-homeserver:~$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o mpqemubr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i mpqemubr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i mpqemubr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i mpqemubr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i mpqemubr0 -o mpqemubr0 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.57.240.0/24 -i mpqemubr0 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.57.240.0/24 -o mpqemubr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i mpqemubr0 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o mpqemubr0 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o mpqemubr0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o mpqemubr0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o mpqemubr0 -p udp -m udp --sport 67 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.57.240.0/24 ! -d 10.57.240.0/24 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.57.240.0/24 ! -d 10.57.240.0/24 -p udp -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.57.240.0/24 ! -d 10.57.240.0/24 -p tcp -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.57.240.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.57.240.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "generated for Multipass network mpqemubr0" -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 ! -d 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.5
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  3 01:27:53 2022
```

UPDATE:
When i'm connecting to my laptop from 10.57.240.47 i see connection from 192.168.1.5, not from 10.57.240.47

on 10.57.240.47:

```
ubuntu@primary:~$ nc -v 192.168.1.137 5000
Connection to 192.168.1.137 5000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
test
```

on laptop:

```
$ nc -vl 5000
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 2, port 5000)
Connection from h3x-homeserver 51354 received!
test
```

Comment: "Destination Port Unreachable" often suggests a firewall problem. If you run `tcpdump` on your machine at `10.57.240.47`, do you see the ICMP echo requests coming in on the interface? If not, do they show up on the *host* interface?

Comment: @larsks on 10.57.240.47 no ICMP requests. On homeserver there are
01:18:21.486426 IP 192.168.1.137 > 10.57.240.47: ICMP echo request, id 22426, seq 1, length 64

01:18:21.486483 IP homeserver.lan > 192.168.1.137: ICMP 10.57.240.47 protocol 1 port 24144 unreachable, length 92

Comment: also im receiving message `From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.5)` when pinging smth on 10.57.240.0/24

Comment: Please update your question to include the output of `ip addr` , `ip route` and `iptables-save` on `homeserver`.

Comment: @larsks updated.